# Is there an AMQP data connector in Palantir Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-data-connection

I'm mostly interested in ingesting data but would also be curious to know if there a also a way to emit messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, apparently not at the moment but new connectors are being developed all the time, so in the future users should reach out to their Palantir representative to double check.